# Giving a value to char pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C, and I have come across char pointers, which do not really make sense to me...

I have seen many people do this:

```
char* something = "Hi";
printf("%s", something);
```

I thought a pointer is pointing to the memory adress of the variable? Should you not do something like *something = "Hi"?

Comment: `char* something` `char *something` is same

Comment: `I thought a pointer is pointing to the memory address of the variable`. `something` is pointing to **Hi**

Comment: But shouldn't something be the adress then? And *something is the string value?

Comment: According to K&R when using `char* something = "Hi";`  this form if you want to modify the string you will get unspecified behavior !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A char pointer points to a single byte of memory. Since the string `"Hi"` takes more memory than a single byte, the char pointer just holds the address of the first character in the string, `'H'`.

To demonstrate this, try dereferencing the pointer and printing it:

```
printf("%c\n", *something);
```

Otherwise, the `%s` option of printf (the one you are using) expects a pointer to the first character of a string and will print until it hits a zero byte.

Answer (score 1):

It works. In the memory 3 Byte will be allocated for "Hi": 'H''i''\0', because " " means, that it is a string, which is terminated with 0 (\0). And you would like to point to the start of this sections, so "something" will contain the memory address of 'H'. In printf() %s means you will have a "string", which is terminated by 0 (\0). The printf will start to display characters from the address of H, which is saved in the "something" pointer and finishes when \0 found.